# Localization with a language other than the default options, such as Swedish

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, xib

I want my app to default to using English, but have an option for Swedish. Any device that wants a localization other than Swedish should use the English version of the app.

When I try to add a localization to my project, the only options I see are English, Japanese, French, German, and "Base".

How do I set up Swedish localization in Xcode?

Comment: Can't you add Swedish Localization to your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you go to your `Project --> Info`

[image]

Then in `Localizations` submenu add your language.

Then in your xib/storyboard you can select it from the right menu (`File Inspector`):

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you. Now I get the possibility to select languages and add files as I want and change the text labels in a xib file. So far so good. But it does not work when testing on my phone. It is english all the time despite setting it up for swedish. What do I do wrong here. I know I have tested this earlier and it worked but that was with iOS6.Now I use iOS7 and Xcode5